# Cambiar de pagina sin afectar ruta - Laravel

Tags: laravel, paginación, blade

Estoy utilizando paginacion con laravel, el problema es que tengo una ruta get definida y en funcion.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/university?type=private
```

Al momento de cambiar de pagina la ruta cambia

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/university?page=2
```

Eliminando consigo `?type=private` que es algo necesario.

Cambio la pagina de la siguiente manera:

```
<a href="{{ $universities->url($i) }}" ...</a>
```

¿como podria evitar que me borre la ruta? de tal manera que queden ambas en funcion.

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que sigas las convenciones del paginador de Laravel, utiliza el método appends en el paginador para agregar los parámetros actuales de la URL a la «nueva» url con las páginas:

```
{{ $universities->appends(request()->input())->links() }}
```

En la documentación de Laravel encuentras toda la información: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#displaying-pagination-results